# ORACLE # IF..THEN.. GETTING CODE IN OUTPUT

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

While executing below program, If I am getting the desire result but my code is also coming in OUTPUT Window of sql developer. How I can avoid the code coming in my output?

Can you please explain what wrong I have done?

```
Accept Num Prompt ' Please Enter Number between 0-9';
Declare
NUM number := &NUM;
BEGIN

IF Num = 0 Then 
Dbms_Output.put_line('You have Entered Zer0');
ELSIF NUM =1 Then 
Dbms_Output.put_line('You have Entered one'); 
ELSIF NUM =2 Then
Dbms_Output.put_line('You have Entered TWO'); 
ELSIF NUM =3 Then
Dbms_Output.put_line('You have Entered THREE'); 
ELSIF NUM =4 Then
Dbms_Output.put_line('You have Entered FOUR'); 
ELSIF NUM =5 Then
Dbms_Output.put_line('You have Entered FIVE'); 
ELSIF NUM =6 Then
Dbms_Output.put_line('You have Entered SIX'); 
ELSIF NUM =7 Then
Dbms_Output.put_line('You have Entered SEVEN');
ELSIF NUM =8 Then
Dbms_Output.put_line('You have Entered EIGHT'); 
ELSIF NUM =9 Then
Dbms_Output.put_line('You have Entered NINE');
ELSE
Dbms_Output.put_line('You have Entered more than single digit');
END IF;
END;
```

Output of SQL Develper:

```
old:Declare
NUM number := &NUM;
BEGIN

IF Num = 0 Then 
Dbms_Output.put_line('You have Entered Zer0');
ELSIF NUM =1 Then 
Dbms_Output.put_line('You have Entered one'); 
ELSIF NUM =2 Then
Dbms_Output.put_line('You have Entered TWO'); 
ELSIF NUM =3 Then
Dbms_Output.put_line('You have Entered THREE'); 
ELSIF NUM =4 Then
Dbms_Output.put_line('You have Entered FOUR');  
ELSIF NUM =5 Then
Dbms_Output.put_line('You have Entered FIVE'); 
ELSIF NUM =6 Then
Dbms_Output.put_line('You have Entered SIX'); 
ELSIF NUM =7 Then
Dbms_Output.put_line('You have Entered SEVEN');
ELSIF NUM =8 Then
Dbms_Output.put_line('You have Entered EIGHT'); 
ELSIF NUM =9 Then
Dbms_Output.put_line('You have Entered NINE');
ELSE
Dbms_Output.put_line('You have Entered more than single digit');
END IF;
END;
new:Declare
NUM number := 0;
BEGIN

IF Num = 0 Then 
Dbms_Output.put_line('You have Entered Zer0');
ELSIF NUM =1 Then 
Dbms_Output.put_line('You have Entered one'); 
ELSIF NUM =2 Then
Dbms_Output.put_line('You have Entered TWO'); 
ELSIF NUM =3 Then
Dbms_Output.put_line('You have Entered THREE'); 
ELSIF NUM =4 Then
Dbms_Output.put_line('You have Entered FOUR'); 
ELSIF NUM =5 Then
Dbms_Output.put_line('You have Entered FIVE'); 
ELSIF NUM =6 Then
Dbms_Output.put_line('You have Entered SIX'); 
ELSIF NUM =7 Then
Dbms_Output.put_line('You have Entered SEVEN');
ELSIF NUM =8 Then
Dbms_Output.put_line('You have Entered EIGHT'); 
ELSIF NUM =9 Then
Dbms_Output.put_line('You have Entered NINE');
ELSE
Dbms_Output.put_line('You have Entered more than single digit');
END IF;
END;
anonymous block completed
You have Entered Zer0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line to the top of the script:

```
SET VERIFY OFF
```

By default, `VERIFY` is `ON` and causes SQL*Plus (and SQL Developer) to display code before and after replacing substitution variables. Setting it to `OFF` disables this behavior.